# Fourier Transform: why time reversal in freq domain is the same as complex conjugate?

Tags: fourier-transform

have a function $x(-t)$, and I take the Fourier transform of this function:

$\mathcal{F} \Big[x(-t) \Big] = X(-\omega)$

Why does time reversal of the frequency $\omega$ equal the complex conjugate?

$X(-\omega) = X^{*}(\omega)$

Answer (score 1):

So the exact equations will vary depending on whether your frequency and time domains are being viewed as discrete or continuous (e.g. DFT, CTFT), but all have the core property of some summation over $t$ of something similar to $x(t) * e^{i * t * w}$.

The complex conjugate comes from the fact that $e^{-w} = (e^w)^*$
By substituting w with -w and assuming the function x(t) is real, we can see that $\mathcal{X}^*(w)$ is roughly a sum of $x^*(t)(e^{i * t * w})^* = x(t) e^{-i * t * w}$. This summation/integration becomes then $\mathcal{X}(-w)$. Note that this assumes $x$ is real in time domain.

If you aren't sure why the complex conjugate is of the complex exponential is just a negative exponent, consider Euler's formula:

$ e^{i * t} = cos(t) + i*sin(t)$

$ (e^{i * t})^* = (cos(t) + i*sin(t))^* = (cos(t))^* + (i*sin(t))^*$

$cos(t)$ and $sin(t)$ are real, so:

$ (e^{i * t})^* = cos(t) + sin(t) * i^* = cos(t) - i * sin(t) $

Given that sine is odd ($sin(-t) = -sin(t)$) and cosine is even ($cos(-t) = cos(t)$):

$ (e^{i * t})^* = cos(t) - i * sin(t) = cos(-t) + i * sin(-t) = e^{-i * t}$

Comment: what about CTFT case?

Comment: Would be the same thing. All forms of fourier only have $w$ in the complex exponential, and every other value of the equation (assuming $x$ is real) would be real. For ctft, it would be the integral of $x(t) e^{2*\pi*i*w*t)$. As long as $x$ is real, the complex conjugate will be $x(t) e^{- 2*\pi*i*w*t)$, so $\mathcal{X}*(w) = \mathcal{X}(-w)$. This works for all fourier transforms of real functions as they all have this summation of exponential structure

Answer (score 1):

Your statement hols only  if your function $f$ to which the Fourier transformation is applied is real:

$$(\mathcal{F}f)(t):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2\pi i x t} f(x)\,dx$$

Then

$$ (\mathcal{F}f)(-t) =\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{2\pi i x t} f(x)\,dx=\overline{\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2\pi i x t} \overline{f}(x)\,dx}=\overline{(\mathcal{F}\overline{f})(t)}$$

If your function $f$ is real valued, then $\overline{f}=f$ and so
$(\mathcal{F}f)(-t)=\overline{(\mathcal{F}f)(t)}$